# Lightgbm, Force use of all features

Tags: lightgbm

I am playing a bit with lightgbm to classify some binary files, after a lot of search I am still unable to find a way to force lightgbm to use all data I provide from my dataset. When the training starts it says I have 83390 data (files in my case), but only 5XXX features used.
I tried to change some parameters like "min_data_in_leaf" but it doesnt really change.

Can someone explain me how to tune Lightgbm to make it use all data I have ?

```
2019-02-16 17:02:03,969 Train model
[LightGBM] [Warning] Starting from the 2.1.2 version, default value for the "boost_from_average" parameter in "binary" objective is true.
This may cause significantly different results comparing to the previous versions of LightGBM.
Try to set boost_from_average=false, if your old models produce bad results
[LightGBM] [Info] Number of positive: 41695, number of negative: 41695
[LightGBM] [Info] Total Bins 494351
[LightGBM] [Info] Number of data: 83390, number of used features: 5937
[LightGBM] [Info] [binary:BoostFromScore]: pavg=0.500000 -> initscore=0.000000
```

Comment: Dino, hello. Did you manage to find a working way? I need to evaluate the gain of all features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LightGBM will auto disable the feature that cannot be splitted, like the feature with almost all values are zeros (or the same).

Answer (score 0):

Number of data is the number of rows of your data, and number of features is the number of columns of your data. If your data is a 2d array or dataframe with shape of 83390*5937, lgbm is using all of your data.

Comment: Ok, but my features array is suppose to be a array of 7125 not 5937, it means some of the columns are ignored because they are similar ?

Comment: It ignores all features that can not be used to improve classification.

Answer (score 0):

As @yanqi told, LightGBM will auto-disable the feature which can not be splitted. So if you force to use all the features those features would not impact anything on the model performance. So better not to use those features to save computational resources.